# trying to update the category table with entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a data gridview and i have two text boxes when i click on the  data gridview row the corresponding row values are filled in text boxes ......

upto this working fine....

i want to update the category table when i click on the save button

i have category table with

```
                              category_id
                              category_name
                              category_description
```

and this is my code :

```
                 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                 {

                      if(dgvCategories.SelectedRows.Count >0)
                      {
                     int updatecategoryid = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCategories.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                     category categoryupdate = new category() { category_Id = updatecategoryid };
                     categoryupdate.category_Name = tbCategoryName.Text;
                     categoryupdate.category_Description = tbCategoryDescription.Text;
                     dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                     }

                }
```

it does not update the category table.....

would any one help on this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dbcontext` has no way of knowing that you are updating anything. Since you mentioned "updating" the table, here is one way of updating your categories table.

Updating:

```
var category = dbcontext.Categories.Where(c => c.category_id.Equals(catId)).Single();
if (category != null)
{
    category.category_name = tbCategoryName.Text;
    category.category_description = tbCategoryDescription.Text;
}
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Now, if you want to insert on your categories table...

Inserting:

```
category c = new category();
c.category_name = tbCategoryName.Text;
c.category_description = tbCategoryDescription.Text;
dbcontext.Categories.AddObject(c);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
return c.category_id; //(optional) if you want the unique id to be returned
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dbcontext` has no way to know that you created a `category` object unless you tell it.

```
                 category categoryupdate = new category() { category_Id = updatecategoryid };
                 dbcontext.Attach(categoryupdate);
                 categoryupdate.category_Name = tbCategoryName.Text;
                 categoryupdate.category_Description = tbCategoryDescription.Text;
                 dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Error :An object with a null EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context.     InvalidoperationException was unhaldled..

Comment: @user852714: In that case you'll probably have to generate the entity key based on the category ID. It'll be easier to use Bobby's answer, which should work fine. (And if you get a chance, try upgrading to EF 4)